# fastboot flash super.img with FAILED (Sparse file is too large or invalid)

Tags: sparse-matrix, fastboot

extracting vendor_dlkm.img (38 MB) to disk... took 0.090s

archive does not contain 'vendor_other.img'

Sending sparse 'super' 1/1 (4194303 KB)            FAILED (Sparse file is too large or invalid)

fastboot: error: Command failed

Press any key to exit...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: It does not work when i change my USB port.
It does not work when i change my wireline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SDK platform 33.03 instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution - Use older version of the Platform SDK tool - refer [this page](https://support.google.com/pixelphone/thread/210635378/sending-sparse-super-sparse-file-is-too-large-or-invalid?hl=en) for more details.

Nitin